# Is it safe to expose the development stack ( framework, server, language etc )

Tags: open-source, project

I run a small startup and have developed some web applications. We use open source technologies heavily and I want to give proper attribution to everything that we use.

The only thing I am concern about is it safe to expose everything? Such as webserver, development language and framework etc. Are there any pitfalls of doing so?

e.g. One particular concern is if some vulnerability be discovered in framework, application can be easy target until gets a patch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more one knows the more one can leverage. Said that, it shouldn't be to much of a problem if you build your web application with security in mind.

Comment: And if you didn't, someone will notice sooner or later anyway. "Security through obscurity" it useless - i.e. it isn't any more secure just because the algorithms/languages/servers/etc. are unknown.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be an issue - many companies make public the fact that they use particular open source solutions.

The main pitfalls are the obvious security related ones: have you changed all the default admin passwords etc.?